# Determining if I need quotes in HTML with django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a `dict` in python that is something like the following:

```
d = {'key1': .98, 'key2': 'some_str', 
     #...
    }
```

In this dictionary some keys will be mapped to `float` and others will be mapped to `str`

In my HTML I am doing something like the following:

```
html_dict = {
{% for k, v in my_dict.items %}
     {{ k }}: "{{ v }}",
{% endfor %}
};
```

However this approach wraps the floats in quotes as well, which is what I don't want.  But if I don't know wrap them in quotes the HTML doesn't understand that they are are string values.  I would ideally like something like the following:

```
html_dict = {
{% for k, v in my_dict.items %}
     {% if check_v_is_str %}
         {{ k }}: "{{ v }}",
     {% else %}
         {{ k }}: {{ v }},
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
};
```

Comment: Aside from Daniel Roseman's correct answer, just doing `{{ my_dict }}` would give you the correct values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do this. You are manually trying to replicate a JS data structure, when there already exists a well-defined structure that both Python and JS know about, namely JSON. Use that instead. Convert the dict to JSON in your view, and pass it to the template where it can be output directly.

Comment: So I tried doing this, and I chisled down my post to this small case.  But ultimatley what I have originally is a `dataframe`.  And what I wanted to do was pass in `df.to_json(orient='records')`.  And on the HTML side I do $scope.my_variable = {{ pass_json }} and I'm getting errors there with quotes

Comment: Looking at it more carefully the jsonified dataframe looks something like: `'[{"something": 1.0}]'`.  The " appear to be a problem in HTML

Comment: You might need to pass the output through the Django [`|safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter so that the quotes aren't escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a filter called "check_v_type" to call in your template as follows:

```
{% if v|check_v_type == 'str' %}
```

But I don't think that makes for good logic. Generally, you want to avoid function calls in your templates. Instead, in your view, you could create a dictionary of tuples of the form:

```
d = {'key1': (.98, False), 'key2': ('some_str', True), #...}
```

You could then use the boolean in each tuple to decide how to format the value in your HTML.